# How do I cast an output of my IF function in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, casting

How do I change Small_Bag_Percent as Numeric upto 2 decimals?

Here is the query:

```
SELECT
  Total_Bags,
  Small_Bags,
  Large_Bags,
  XLarge_Bags,
  Small_Bags+Large_Bags+XLarge_Bags AS Total_Bags_Calc,
(IF
  (Total_Bags >0,
    (Small_Bags/Total_Bags)*100,
    0) Small_Bag_Percent
FROM
  `leafy-racer-348015.AvocadoPrices.AvocadoPrice`
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a cast operator.

If you already know that your value is in decimal, then to get 2 decimal rounded all you need is to use round function:

Sample:

```
select round(123.42321312, 2) as rounded_val_2_decimals
```

Gives back: 123.42

Comment: The below seems correct now-
IF
  (Total_Bags >0,
    round((Small_Bags/Total_Bags)*100,2),0) AS Small_Bag_Percent

Comment: glad it worked for u. If round is what you were looking for, you can accept the answer. Thx